# Avoid loading css from parent theme

Tags: functions, child-theme, parent-theme

In a parent theme (Foodica Pro) functions.php I have function *foodica_scripts()*, where css and js are loaded in page header, including:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'media-queries', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/media-queries.css', array(), WPZOOM::$themeVersion );
```

This media-queries.css will take a lot of work to overwrite (using different breakpoints).
I want to avoid loading this css file, but without touching parent theme.
Is there any way to do it in child theme only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child theme (which I am assuming you are using) `functions.php` file:

```php
function wpse_356175_assets() {

    wp_dequeue_style( 'media-queries' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_356175_assets' );
```

Utilise `wp_dequeue_style` and or `wp_deregister_style` depending on how the stylesheet was registered/enqueued.

If necessary adjust the priority of your action to fire after the registered/enqueued file from the parent theme, e.g:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_356175_assets', 100 );`

Useful documentation:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_style/